# Where can I create a bitcoin address?

Tags: client, address

I wish to start mining but I could not since I do not have a bitcoin address. Where can I create this address?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the Qt Client, click on the **Receive** button on the top, you will have one address there by default. Click on **New Address** at the bottom left to get a new address.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **safe** bitcoin address from :

- Your pc
- Blockchain.info
- Cex.io
- Just-dice.com
- Btc-e.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.bitaddress.org

It is an interesting, lightweight, trustable and really easy to use solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have bitcoin-qt installed you can sign up on www.blockchain.info to acquire a bitcoin address